# Sampling distribution of the sample standard deviation

Tags: sampling, unbiased-estimator

I'm trying to recreate the graph from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StandardDeviationDistribution.html) using equations (2) and (3), but I've yet to do so successfully.  I'm not sure that equation (2) is correct.  I traced it back to the original source [here](http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/bitstream/1/2025521/1/G2257.pdf) (see equation 7.39) where an unbiasing constant $c_5$ is used.

Am I missing something with how I'm supposed to calculate/apply the unbiasing constant in this formula?  I just don't see how they arrive at the graph using the formulas on the Mathworld page.

Comment: I believe there is a typographical error on that Wolfram page: "$\sigma^2 = Ns^2/(N-1)$" should instead read "$\sigma^2 = E[Ns^2/(N-1)].$"  With that in mind, define a function $f[s\_,n\_,\sigma\_]$ as given in equation (2) and plot it as in `Plot[Evaluate@Table[f[s, n, 1], {n, 2, 12, 2}], {s, 0, 2}]`.

Comment: @whuber If I'm looking to calculate $\sigma^2$ what effect will the expectation add?  Say $s = 2$ and $N = 10$, how does my answer change?

Comment: You cannot calculate $\sigma^2$: it must be specified.  It is a parameter of the underlying Normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

My apology for having to paste in a picture of equations, but I am still learning how to format equations properly using MathJax and I will replace the picture ASAP!

[image: PDFs for s expressions]

The "unbiasing constants" are $E[•]/\sigma$, as relevant.

Below is a plot of six $s'$ PDFs that I computed from the $p_{s'}(s')$ PDF given above. These are for N = 2, 4, ..., 12, with the same color coding as at the Wolfram link, and $\sigma = 1$. So $p_{s'}(s') = f_N(s)$ and $\nu = N-1$. N.B. In Wolfram's $f_N(s)$, the $s$ is what I call $s'$ above.

[image: Plot of s' PDFs]